# Can't add to a list from async function

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i try to learn Xamarin.Forms and async methods. But since this morning i'm stuck :(.
I can't add a single string to my list. I used stop point on every line of my function (the first i will send) and every variable as what it should have inside. But for a reason i don't understand these data won't add to my lists. The problem most likely come from my approximative comprehension of async methods.

My goal is to create some presets for my small app. The user can create a preset by pressing a button and is saved as a text file with the name the user provided via an Entry(Xamarin). I want to use a Picker(Xamarin) to select the preset to use. But he stay empty except for the one i declared by hand in the MainPage constructor.

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and PCLstorage.

My lists declaration:

```
public List<IFile> presetFilesList = new List<IFile>();
public List<string> presetNamesList = new List<string>();
```

The call for my function:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //set preset picker
        presetNamesList.Add("Choose a preset here");
        var test = GetAllfilesInSiRoDataAsync();
    }
```

and here is the function:

```
private async Task<bool> GetAllfilesInSiRoDataAsync()
    {
        bool result = false;
        await Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            IFolder root = PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder folder = await root.GetFolderAsync("SiRoData", System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
            var siroFolder = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

            foreach (IFile file in siroFolder)
            {
                presetFilesList.Add(file);
                string nomFichier = file.Name;
                nomFichier = nomFichier.Remove(nomFichier.Length - 4);
                presetNamesList.Add(nomFichier);
            }

            presetPicker.ItemsSource = presetNamesList;
            presetPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
            result = true;
            });
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks for reading this ! :)

Comment: Async is creating a different thread and you can't add items from one thread to another thread.

Comment: Calling an async method from a constructor is not good. You cannot wait it so it will run in parallel and change your fiels when you probably do not expect it.

Comment: @jdweng ok, but i only you one here no ? Or does the anonymous async count as one ?

Comment: @KlausGütter ok, and how could i call it on startup so the picker is set up on launch ?

Comment: The thread runs and is blocked by the await. Once the await unblocks you are back to the original thread.  The Task.Run() is the issue.  Everything inside the Task.Run() is a different thread from the List<> objects.

Comment: ok, so i only need the async method but not the Task.Run() so that's 2 different things ? i'm trying rignt now and i removed my call from the constructor, i added a button to load all the presets.

Comment: You can call an async method from OnAppearing

Comment: Please add to question any **xaml or c# code** that uses those lists. You mention "picker" - are these used as "ItemsSource"? If so, there are many previous questions about the problem you are having; google `xamarin itemssource not seeing items added to list`.

Comment: @Jason thanks, i did that thats better than my old button...

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes it's used as a itemSource sorry i should have mentionned it. I'm going to check, thanks.

Comment: hey, last question... Is it possible to create an async function that return a list of string and assign these string to a local variable ?

Comment: i finally found the solution, thanks for the help :)

Comment: I suggest you can post your solution with detailed information as this will help others who face the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Sure i'll do it when i got home :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to work i first changed my variable declaration, **removed** the "Names" list (for the names displayed in the picker i now use the *IFile* property: **Name** (filename)).

**Code:**

```
        public IList<IFile> presetFilesList;
```

I also changed the way to fetch the files, i stopped trying to do everything in the **GetAllGetAllfilesInSiRoDataAsync()** function (it's easier to use now). This function just go in the folder takes all the files in it and return an *IList of IFile*.

**Code:**

```
private static async Task<IList<IFile>> GetAllfilesInSiRoDataAsync()
    {
        IFolder root = PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await root.GetFolderAsync("SiRoData", System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        var siroFolder = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        return siroFolder;
    }
```

I now call this function on the **OnAppearing()** function (as jason said it). In this function i simply assign the return of **GetAllFiles()** to a new temporary list:

**Code:**

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        IList<IFile> list = await GetAllfilesInSiRoDataAsync();

        PassTo(list);

    }
```

Since i could not pass my List of IFiles from an async function to my *presetFilesList* (declared on the first step). i created a function to do it.

Then i pass this list to the **PassTo()** function that takes *IList of IFile*
as a parameter.

Code:

```
        private void PassTo(IList<IFile> presetsList)
    {
        presetFilesList = presetsList;
        presetPicker.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IList)presetFilesList;
    }
```

I also made some change in my *xaml*: i created a **Binding** for **ItemSource** to my list. After that i set **ItemDisplayBinding** to be *Name* so the value my picker displays is the *Name* property of the *Ifile*.

```
<Picker x:Name="presetPicker" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 0, 30, 0" SelectedIndexChanged="presetPicker_SelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding presetFilesList}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" Title="Choose a preset" TitleColor="White"/>
```

Thanks for the help :) ,sorry for the bad english.

Comment: I have to wait for 3 hours :/ but i'll do just in case someone needs it.